# SP2013, When I click on a username I got the error "User not found"

Tags: error, search-results, people-search

I am using SP2013. I have created a new page. On this page I have a search textbox and a search result web part. In this search result web part you see default all users. So it is filtered on users. Its like a people search. When I click on a username I get an error:

[image]

Translated from Dutch to English:

> User not found.

This is the URL of the hyperlink on the username which I have clicked:

```
http://myProfile.myCompany.com/Person.aspx?accountname=MYCOMPANY%255CVERWERT
```

Why do I got this error? I've got this error on all users in my search result web part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **bug** or at least unexpected behavior, introduced on the April 2014 Cumulative Update. I've been monitoring the solving process of this issue and even the latest CU of August 2014 seems to **not** fix this issue.

There are couple of posts about this subject including temporary workarounds. See:

http://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/06/workaround-ms14-022-double-encoding-bug/ (article)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17005728-3e68-49f5-8882-85cc8260e53b/people-search-error?forum=sharepointgeneral (MSDN post)

Update: The bug has been fixed in the September 2014 Cumulative Update. The bug was known as *Double Encoding Bug*. Source: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Regressions/sp2013sep2014cu.aspx

Comment: The js change works:)

Comment: This bug is fixed now. See my updated answer.